# Concatenar vs sumar en js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola tengo un problema muy básico, pero no entiendo porque pasa, tengo una serie de valores que tomo de unos `input` y mi objetivo es sumar estos valores, pero el problema de cuando trato de sumarlos , estoy concatenando en su lugar.
Aquí está mi script.

```js
var lun, mart, mier, juev, vier, sab, domin;
lun = $('#lun').val();
mart = $('#mart').val();
mier = $('#mier').val();
juev = $('#juev').val();
vier = $('#vier').val();
sab = $('#sab').val();
domin = $('#domin').val();

$('#ventasError').addClass('hidden');
lun = parseFloat(lun).toFixed(2);
mart = parseFloat(mart).toFixed(2);
mier = parseFloat(mier).toFixed(2);
juev = parseFloat(juev).toFixed(2);
vier = parseFloat(vier).toFixed(2);
sab = parseFloat(sab).toFixed(2);
domin = parseFloat(domin).toFixed(2);

 
let sumVSem = lun + mart + mier + juev + vier + sab + domin;
debugger //justo sumVSem  aquí me tira 1.001.001.001.001.001.001.00 en lugar 7.00
sumVSem = parseFloat(sumVSem).toFixed(2);
$('#promSemanal').val(sumVSem);
```

Alguien puede decirme que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: El método [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed#Valor_Devuelto) devuelve: ***Una cadena que representa el número dado, usando notación de punto fijo.*** Es por ello que estás concatenando, te sugiero que primero sumes y de último usa el método `toFixed()`. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let sumVSem = parseFloat(lun) + parseFloat(mart) + parseFloat(mier) + parseFloat(juev) + parseFloat(vier) + parseFloat(sab) + parseFloat(domin);
```

Con eso ya te debería funcionar.

Answer (score 4):

Buen día

Como ya te dijeron arriba, el metodo `toFixed()` devuelve un string, si quieres mantenerlo así, puedes modificar tu código de esta manera, agregando un `parseFloat()` a cada variable a la hora de hacer la suma.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() { 
  var lun, mart, mier, juev, vier, sab, domin;
  lun = $('#lun').val();
  mart = $('#mart').val();
  mier = $('#mier').val();
  juev = $('#juev').val();
  vier = $('#vier').val();
  sab = $('#sab').val();
  domin = $('#domin').val();

  $('#ventasError').addClass('hidden');
  lun = parseFloat(lun).toFixed(2);
  mart = parseFloat(mart).toFixed(2);
  mier = parseFloat(mier).toFixed(2);
  juev = parseFloat(juev).toFixed(2);
  vier = parseFloat(vier).toFixed(2);
  sab = parseFloat(sab).toFixed(2);
  domin = parseFloat(domin).toFixed(2);


  let sumVSem = parseFloat(lun) + parseFloat(mart) + parseFloat(mier) + parseFloat(juev) + parseFloat(vier) + parseFloat(sab) + parseFloat(domin);
  console.log(sumVSem);
   //justo sumVSem  aquí me tira 1.001.001.001.001.001.001.00 en lugar 7.00
  // sumVSem = parseFloat(sumVSem).toFixed(2);
  // $('#promSemanal').val(sumVSem);
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
 
</script>
<body>
 <input type="text" id="lun" value="1">
 <input type="text" id="mart" value="1">
 <input type="text" id="mier" value="1">
 <input type="text" id="juev" value="1">
 <input type="text" id="vier" value="1">
 <input type="text" id="sab" value="1">
 <input type="text" id="domin" value="1">
</body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 4):

Aunque ya tienes una respuesta aceptada, mi respuesta se enfocará en optimizar un poco lo que estás intentando hacer.

Estás repitiendo el mismo código 7 veces (1 vez por cada día de la semana representado en tus elementos `<input>`).

Una forma de evitar esta repetición sería listar tus elementos en un tipo `array` y usar los método propios del mismo.

Supongamos que tu HTML viene dado así (todos los elementos tipo `<input>` son hijos directos de un elemento padre tipo `<div>`):

```html
<div id="dias">
  <input type="text" id="lun" value="0">
  <input type="text" id="mar" value="0">
  ...
  <input type="text" id="dom" value="0">
</div>
```

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
let valores = [];

if($('#dias').children().length) {
  $('#dias').children().each((index, element) => {
    valores.push(parseFloat(element.value));
  });
}

let suma = valores.length ? valores.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + curr).toFixed(2) : "0.00";

console.log(suma);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dias">
  <input type="text" id="lun" value="0.1234">
  <input type="text" id="mar" value="0.2345">
  <input type="text" id="mie" value="0.3456">
  <input type="text" id="jue" value="0.4567">
  <input type="text" id="vie" value="0.5678">
  <input type="text" id="sab" value="0.6789">
  <input type="text" id="dom" value="0.7890">
</div>
```

Como puedes observar, declaro un tipo `array` para almacenar los valores de cada elemento `input` convertidos en tipo `Number` usando `parseFloat()`. Luego uso el método [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para sumar todos los valores del `array` y devolver un valor único, al cual luego le aplico el método `toFixed()` para obtener el resultado deseado.

Con esto el código es más limpio, y menos repetitivo.